# Sending server array to javascript using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

How does one access server information from javascript? Here is the portion of my flask code dealing with this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/newtemplate')
def render_plot():
    return render_template('template.html')

@app.route('/makelist')
def run_script():
    list = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
    return list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Here is how I am trying to access list in template.html (p id, ol id not in js).

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<ol id="new-projects"></ol>

<script>
var myList = $( "#new-projects" ).load( "makelist" );
</script>
```

I have imported jquery. I am getting a 500 error for makelist.

Comment: Did you try specifying the method allowed in the decorator? Maybe like this: `@app.route('/makelist', methods=['GET'])`

Comment: I think I have figured this out, I left out methods=['GET']. I may post again here if problems persist.